# Young adult/kids' novel about kids who travel to a planet inhabited by telepathic cats

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, space

Thanks for any ideas folks may have about this. I read the book as a schoolkid in the late 70s or early 80s. I thought it would be a simple search; I'm pretty sure it was called something obvious like "Space Cats," but I've searched many variants of that and haven't been able to find it. It was about a boy and a girl, I think brother and sister, who are brought to a planet of cats, where all communication, with other beings and with the machines that dispense their food, is by telepathy; there is no speech. The kids are first put through this machine which cleans them and dresses them in cozy suits. It was for fairly young kids, I think--I was probably 10 when I read it. The cover of the paperback copy I had definitely included the boy and girl in their yellow fuzzy suits that had been dispensed by the cleaning machine.

Comment: The ones at http://anthrozine.com/site/lbry/cat.novels.html didn't spark any recognition in me from your description, but you might have better luck.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect you're thinking of [Star Ka'at](https://www.goodreads.com/series/120625-star-ka-at) and/or the sequels, by Andre Norton:

> Two Earth children are taken to the world of the Star Ka'ats, intelligent, telepathic cat creatures.

The timing is right (1976) and they were for young readers; I can't find a sufficiently detailed synopsis to confirm whether or not the specific details you mention match up, but they did at least involve a brother and sister and telepathic cats.  (Plus, of course, the title is very close to what you thought it was, while still sufficiently different to make a Google search fruitless.)

Possibly [this](https://schlockvalue.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/star-kaat-world.png) was the cover on the copy you had?  It has the yellow suits.

Comment: Harry, you are amazing. Thank you so much! You even found the cover! I am so grateful.