# Trying to remember a Sci-fi book about telepathic cats :)

Tags: story-identification, books

When I was in middle school (late 80's early 90's), I read a book that was about a futuristic society where there are human-sized cats that live with people as companions. They could also move through walls and had telepathic abilities.

I know that's not much to go on but I'm hoping MAYBE someone out there read the same book and remembers what it's called!

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Were they cat-like humanoids?  Or just really big cats?  Not [Star Ka-ats](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/177280/5930) by any chance?

Comment: I can think of a couple to give you a place to start, but, it's hard to tell without more detailed description--so, for example, a couple of suggestions here involve telepathy between cats and humans not necessarily from the cat side (e.g. Cordwainer Smith): (1 & 2) 'Catalyst' and 'Catacombs' part of McCaffrey's 'Tales of the Barque Cats', (3) 'The Cats of Seroster' by R. Westall, (4) The Hani in C. Cherryh's Chanur series (5) 'The Ballad of Lost C'Mell' by C. Smith, (6) Lucky in 'The Green Millennium' by F. Leiber (6) The 'Ghattis Tale' series by G. Greeno, (7) 'Telzey Amberdon' by J. Schmitz

Comment: Also the Sholan by Lisanne Norman. Some members definitely have telepathy; can't remember about walking through walls.

Answer (score 3):

Whoop, found this looking for the same books - [Star Ka-at](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/907518.Star_Ka_at) is it!

> Two intriguing stray cats communicate with Jim and Elly Mae, convincing them that the cats are aliens from another planet.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that this is the right book?